# Is it possible to implement "Evernote" Apps shortcut creation using phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent, phonegap-plugins

Is it possible to implement the shortcut creation technique used in "Evernote" app using phonegap plugin.I am trying to do the same using phonegap  and android but unfortunately I am unable to do so.I could easily do that with a native app with android but is it possible in cross platform as well?It would be really helpful if anybody can help me out with this.Thanks!!

Comment: what kind of short cuts u want?post some snap shot

Comment: I want to create shortcut of any page on my app in the homescreen which when clicked would redirect to that particular page.I have seen the native way of doing it in android but I would like to do it using phonegap plugin.